# Pass environment variables to Github action

Tags: github-actions

Github provides secrets, whose values can be used in workflows. Unfortunately, the values of secrets is protected and we can't easily see it in the repo or debug it in the workflow as it is scrubbed.

Is there a way to define an "environment variable" in the repository that can be easily seen and debugged? My use case is for configuration that can be easily modified if the repo is forked.

Comment: If it should be seen and debugged, why not include it in the workflow YAML file rather than secrets?

Comment: If they can be easily seen, then what's the point of having secrets at all?! If they are not secrets, then you can simply do this: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables (see the `Greeting` environment variable)

Comment: I want the values to be easily configured or changed without having to change the code itself.

Comment: @brc-dd thanks for the example. The value of the environment variables in the examples have to be hard-coded, passed by secrets or reference outputs from other steps / jobs. If What I wanted to do is provide input to the workflow file from outside the workflow, without using secrets.

Comment: @AnugerahErlaut You can do something like this: https://github.com/brc-dd/env-from-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store environment variables in an `.env` file like this:

```ini
FOO=bar
```

Then you can write code to append data from that file to `$GITHUB_ENV`:

```yaml
name: CI

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  foo:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: cat .env >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Use the value
        run: echo $FOO
```

You'll need to do `cat .env >> $GITHUB_ENV` (and use `actions/checkout`) for each job where you need to access env vars from that file.

**DO NOT STORE SECRETS IN .env** -- use it only for storing configurations, etc.

Complete code: https://github.com/brc-dd/env-from-file

You can also change `.env` to something like `.env.github` to keep things more organized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Not ideal, but I think this is the closest way to doing it.

Answer (score -1):

FYI: you can pass secret as env variable inside job.

Sample job where I have added foo as a secret in actions workflow:

> name: simple secret
> id: secret_env
> env: 
> foo: ${{ secrets.foo}}
> run: echo $foo **

above is example but ignore code syntax issues because of comments format here..

Comment: you are not supposed to have secrets in env